# Adding an externally accessible method to an activex dll (axvlc.dll)

Tags: c++, c, dll, activex, libvlc

I'm trying to fix/update the VLC ActiveX dll, but am having trouble making new methods visible.

The methods themselves are easy to write and are just c/c++, however somewhere in the project/dll is glue that translates the call between the method in the DLL and the "friendly name" exposed by the activex dll.

For example it already has a  VLCMediaDescription::get_title method, however when accessing it via the activex interface, it's vlc_object.mediaDescription.title

I don't see anything in the .idl file that would do this.

Can anybody toss me a clue where to do the translation?

FWIW, this is Visual Studio 2012.

I've tried using the wizard but it seems to crash quite a bit and hasn't produced anything useful.

An "explain it to me like I'm 5" would be awesome.

Thanks!

Terry

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but if memory serves the idl file should be the thing that creates a typelib that defines the methods and properties and assigns a DISPID to each.  The IDispatch (or IDispatchEx) implementation should be the place where you actually do things in response to the DISPIDs that are defined in the idl file.  I think [ATL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494h01te%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) does some magic with the the typelib, like automatic lookups and dispatching to get_* and put_* or whatever.  Otherwise in your IDispatch implementation you can do lookups in the typelib.  See the automation [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh309494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for documentation of functions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are things that look "sort of" like the stuff you described, but I'm still having problems with the "magic" portion of it.

It has an IDispatch interface, but I'm not seeing any mapping between the external methods and the internal methods.